# Proving: The sum of piecewise linear convex functions is piecewise linear convex

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization

Given that all functions $f_i(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ are piece-wise linear convex functions, prove that $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x)$, for $m$ functions, is also a piece-wise linear convex function.

The definition to be used for piece-wise linear is $f_i = \max\{c_j^Tx + d_j\}$, where $c_j\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d_j\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\forall j\in J$, an index set associated with function $f_i$. And for each function $f_i$ there is a unique index set $J$ and its own sets $\{d_j\},\{c_j\}$.

I dont know how better to word that, sorry.  I hope its well understood.

The definition for a convex function is as such: $\forall x,y$ in domain, $\forall \lambda\in[0,1]$, $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$.

Ive already proven that the sum of convex functions is convex, without regard for piece-wise linear.  What I cant seem to show is that the sum of piece-wise linear functions (using the required definition) is also piece-wise linear.

Ive been working on this for three days.  Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Ive also already proven using an inductive argument that it holds for $m>2$, but I cant seem to show the base case $m=2$. So Ive done quite a bit of this problem already. Just need help proving the base case of the piece-wise linear portion.

Comment: It is important to note that the sum has a finite number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

Note that that $\max_i a_i + \max_j b_j = \max_{i,j} (a_i+b_j)$.

Hence $\max_i (c_i^T x + d_i) + \max_j ({c'_j}^T x + d'_j) = \max_{i,j} ((c_i+c'_j)^T x + (d_i + d'_j) $.

Hence the sum of two convex piecewise linear functions is 
a convex piecewise linear function. Induction shows the rest.

**Aside**:

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ be non empty.

Then $a+b \le \sup A + \sup B$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$ and so $\sup (A+B) \le \sup A + \sup B$.

For any $a\in A, b \in B$ we have $\sup(A+B) \ge a+b$. Now take the $\sup$ over $a \in A$ to get $\sup(A+B) \ge \sup A +b$ and repeat over $b \in B$ to get the desired result.

Comment: This crossed my mind but its not generally true, is it? The sums of maximums dont generally equal the maximum of sums.  Perhaps it does under certain conditions but we are dealing in $n$ dimensional vector space.

Comment: In general, $\sup(A+B) = \sup A+ \sup B$.

Comment: Counter claim: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671111/elegant-proof-that-maximum-of-sums-is-at-most-sum-of-maximums Sums of maxs dont equal maxs of sums

Comment: Am I not understanding something?

Comment: What is the relevance of the linked question?

Comment: I did not write $\max_n (a_n+b_n) = \max_n a_n + \max_n b_n$.

Comment: I dont understand. How is it not related? Did you not write that in the first line of your post? Okay, so the subscripting is different, but the jest is the same, is it not?  The sum of maxs is not the maxs of sums, in general (thats what the link says).

Comment: It is straighforward to prove. Why don't you try?

Comment: I have previously proven in a prior class that sup(A+B)<=sup A + sup B.  Equality does not hold in general, as the link reiterates, not unless there are some additional conditions.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know how else I can write what I have already written. Did you try to prove that $\sup(A+B) = \sup A + \sup B$?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Next.

Comment: You asked for pointers & suggestions and I gave you one. You need to try before getting snarky. I have added an explicit elaboration above.

Comment: I believe that it is easy to miss that the index of the $a$ and $b$ are not linked. Indeed,  $\max_i(a_i) + \max_j(b_j)=\max_{i,j}(a_i + b_j)$ because the max in the right hand side iterates over each _combination_ of $i$ and $j$. The linked question restricts these to the case that $i=j$. In that case, only if the $i$-th elements were both maximal elements, that the maximum over the two sequences is indeed the maximum of the (pairwise sum) of both sequences.

Comment: See my third comment.