# sum of piece wise is piece wise

Tags: proof-writing, linear-programming, alternative-proof, piecewise-continuity

Suppose that $f_{1}(x) ... f_{m}(x)$ are piece wise linear  convex functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R} $ and let given $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{m} f_{i}(x)$. Show that $f(x)$ is also piece wise linear and convex functions.

Using the definition that a piece wise function $ = max_{j=1...m}(c_{j}^{T}x + d_{j})$  $c_{j}$is is a vector and $d_{j}$ is a scalar

How would you prove this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean sum from 1 to m?

Comment: yes. i made the change

Comment: Strangely, someone asked the same question earlier today: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722596/proving-the-sum-of-piecewise-linear-convex-functions-is-piecewise-linear-convex