# Show that if $f_1, \dots, f_m: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are piecewise linear convex, then $\sum_{i=1}^{m}f_i$ is piecewise linear convex as well.

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

**Please note that this is NOT a duplicate of** [Proving: The sum of piecewise linear convex functions is piecewise linear convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722596/proving-the-sum-of-piecewise-linear-convex-functions-is-piecewise-linear-convex).

> **Definition**. Let $\mathbf{c}_1, \dots, \mathbf{c}_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be column vectors, $d_1, \dots, d_m \in \mathbb{R}$, and
>   let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(\mathbf{x}) =
>  \max_{i\in\{1, \dots, m\}}(\mathbf{c}^{\prime}_i\mathbf{x}+d_i)$$ where
>   $\prime$ denotes the matrix transpose. Then $f$ is convex, and we call
>   $f$ a **piecewise linear convex** function.

This is what I would like to prove:

> Suppose $f_1, \dots, f_m: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are piecewise linear convex and let $f = \sum_{i=1}^{m}f_i$. Then $f$ is piecewise linear convex.

**My attempt**:

Let $\mathbf{c}_{11}, \mathbf{c}_{21}, \dots, \mathbf{c}_{N_11}, \mathbf{c}_{12}, \dots, \mathbf{c}_{N_22}, \dots, \mathbf{c}_{N_mm} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d_{11}, \dots , d_{N_mm} \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition of piecewise linear convex, we may write
$$f_i(\mathbf{x}) = \max_{j\in \{1, \dots, N_m\}}(\mathbf{c}^{\prime}_{ji}\mathbf{x}+d_{ji})\text{, } \quad i = 1, \dots, m\text{.}$$
Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in [0,1 ]$. Then
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{m}f_i(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\max_{j\in \{1, \dots, N_m\}}\left[\mathbf{c}^{\prime}_{ji}\mathbf{x}+d_{ji} \right]\text{.}\tag{*}$$
I understand that I need to show that (*) is equal to 
$$\max_{k \in \{1, \dots, N\}}(\mathbf{c}_k^{\prime}\mathbf{x}+d_k)$$
for some $N$, $\mathbf{c}_1, \dots, \mathbf{c}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $d_1, \dots, d_k \in \mathbb{R}$, but I can't figure out how to do this. I don't understand how the answer given at [Proving: The sum of piecewise linear convex functions is piecewise linear convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722596/proving-the-sum-of-piecewise-linear-convex-functions-is-piecewise-linear-convex) applies to this problem.

I have already read the official solution from the solutions manual, but do not understand it. This is exercise 1.2, from *Introduction to Linear Optimization* by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis.

Comment: If you can prove that sum of convex is convex, you are left with to prove that sum of piecewise linear is piecewise linear. For the rest: split the domain for $x$ into finitely many sub-domains where each $f_i$ is represented by a linear function. Sum of linear is linear. Done.

Comment: see: https://math.solverer.com/library/dimitris_bertsimas/introduction_to_linear_optimization/exercise_1-2?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link