# What inequalities can be obtained for summation of piecewise linear convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-inequalities, piecewise-continuity, jensen-inequality

Let $f_i(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a piece-wise linear convex function with $i=1,\dots,m$. We know that $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x)$ is also a piece-wise linear convex function (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722596/proving-the-sum-of-piecewise-linear-convex-functions-is-piecewise-linear-convex)). I am aware of the inequality $$
\sum_{i=1}^n F(x_i) \ge n \cdot F\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\right), 
$$
that comes from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)
. However, the only information used to derive this inequality is convexity of $F(x)$. I was wondering if better inequalities can be obtained given the information that $F(x)$ and $f_i(x)$ are convex **and** piece-wise linear. In the article [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)
 in Wikipedia, it is mentioned that the equality of the above inequality happens if and only if $x_1=\dots=x_n$ or $F(x)$ is **linear**. It seems that the piece-wise linearity of $F$ (or even $f_i(x)$) could be used to obtain better bounds for $\sum_{i=1}^n F(x_i)$ than the above bound. I think similar inequalities have already been proved, but I could not find anything in the internet. What properties/inequalities do you know for such functions?

**Edit:** If that helps, we could consider the condition that $f_i(x):\mathbb{R}_+^n\to\mathbb{R}_+$ instead of the general one $f_i(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can approximate any convex function as well as you like with a piecewise-linear one, so it would be hard to expect you get some really new properties for this class.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks Michal. It would be great if we could find new properties, but at this point I am interested in knowing the existing ones. In particular, are you aware of an existing (maybe common) procedure to approximate a convex function with piecewise linear (convex) functions?