# When the maximum of sum is equal to the sum of maxima

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Consider a function $f:\mathcal{X\times \mathcal{Y}}\rightarrow [0,1]$ where

- $\mathcal{X}\equiv \{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$.
- $\mathcal{Y}\equiv \{y_1,y_2\}$.
- $g(x)\equiv \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}f(x,y)\in (0,1)$ $\forall x\in \mathcal{X}$
- $h(y)\equiv \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}f(x,y)\in (0,1)$ $\forall y\in \mathcal{Y}$
- $\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}g(x)=1$
- $\sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}h(y)=1$
- $g(x_1)>g(x_2)>g(x_3)>g(x_4)$

By the relations above
$$
g(x_1)=\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} g(x)
$$
Is it correct that
$$
g(x_1)=\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}}f(x,y_1)+\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}}f(x,y_2)
$$
?

---

**My thoughts:**
Note that, by definition,
$$
g(x_1)=\max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} (f(x,y_1)+f(x,y_2))
$$
I know that in general the maximum of sums is, **at most**, sum of maximums (e.g., [Elegant proof that maximum of sums is, at most, sum of maximums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671111/elegant-proof-that-maximum-of-sums-is-at-most-sum-of-maximums)). However, I'm wondering whether the above relations are sufficient for such relation to hold with equality. I cannot find a counter-example where the equality is not satisfied. Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_1, y_2) = \frac{1}{6}$, $f(x_2, y_1) =  \frac{1}{4}$,$f(x_3, y_2) =  \frac{1}{4} - \epsilon$, $f(x_2, y_2) = f(x_3, y_1) = 0$, $f(x_4, y_1) = f(x_4, y_2) = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{100}$ Note that this satisfies all your conditions, but $g(x_1) = \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{100} = \max_x f(x, y_1) + \max_x f(x, y_2)$