# Sum of max is greater than max of sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Is the following relation true:
$$
\max \{a_1+b_1, ..., a_n+b_n\}\leq \max \{a_1,...,a_n\}+\max \{b_1,...,b_n\}
$$
$\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ are real numbers?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671111/elegant-proof-that-maximum-of-sums-is-at-most-sum-of-maximums) question is similar, but it seems focused on non-negative numbers. Here $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ can also be negative.

Comment: What if $a_x$ (or $b_x$) has no max at all. E.g. if it's the sequence $1 - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Thanks. $a_x$ and $b_x$ were just numbers (not functions). I have clarified my question.

Comment: The proof in the question which you quoted doesn't seem to use anywhere the fact that $a_i$ or $b_i$ are positive or non-negative. Yes, this statement is true and is pretty trivial. It's proof is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1671118/116591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
a_i+b_i \leq \max \{a_1,...,a_n\}+\max \{b_1,...,b_n\}
$$
for every $i\in{1,\ldots,n}$

Answer (score 0):

It's true. Check that $\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, we have that $\max\{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \ge a_i$ and $\max\{b_1,\dots,b_n\} \ge b_i$, so that:

$$\max\{a_1,\dots,a_n\} + \max\{b_1,\dots,b_n\} \ge a_i + b_i$$

for every index $i$, including the one where the $\max\{a_1+b_1,\dots,a_n+b_n\}$ is attained.